# Using foreman to provision a vm with static ip

Tags: linux, centos6, foreman

I am trying to provision a vm with Centos6.5 on vmware with a static ip address using Foreman 1.5.1.
However, the vm's keeps getting provisioned with a dhcp address.
Im doing a network based install. I created a subnet with all the information about the network (subnet range, gateway, dns server, etc).
In foreman i enabled the dhcp smart proxy for that subnet (disabling it will still give the same result, as long as the dhcp server is running)

Here the relevant lines from the provisioning templates:

Kickstart pxe:

```
<% if @host.operatingsystem.name == 'Fedora' and @host.operatingsystem.major.to_i > 16 -%>`
append initrd=<%= @initrd %> ks=<%= foreman_url('provision')%>?static=yes ks.device=bootif network ks.sendmac ip=<%= @host.ip %> netmask=<%= @host.subnet.mask %> gateway=<%= @host.subnet.gateway %> dns=<%= @host.subnet.dns_primary %>
<% elsif @host.operatingsystem.name != 'Fedora' and @host.operatingsystem.major.to_i >= 7 -%>
`append initrd=<%= @initrd %> ks=<%= foreman_url('provision')%>?static=yes network ks.sendmac ip=        <%= @host.ip %> netmask=<%= @host.subnet.mask %> gateway=<%= @host.subnet.gateway %> dns=<%= @host.subnet.dns_primary %>
<% else -%>
append initrd=<%= @initrd %> ks=<%= foreman_url('provision')%>?static=yes ksdevice=bootif  network kssendmac ip=<%= @host.ip %> netmask=<%= @host.subnet.mask %> gateway=<%= @host.subnet.gateway %> dns=<%= @host.subnet.dns_primary %> 
<% end -%>
```

kickstart default:

```
network --bootproto <%= @static ? "static --ip=#{@host.ip} --netmask=#{@host.subnet.mask} --gateway=#{@host.subnet.gateway} --nameserver=#{[@host.subnet.dns_primary,@host.subnet.dns_secondary].reject{|n| n.blank?}.join(',')}" : 'dhcp' %> --hostname <%= @host %>
```

Everything works, the server is created in vmware, it is installed using pxe, registered in foreman, etc. Except the ip address is not static.

What am i doing wrong here?

The actual ks file after the installation contains the following line:

```
network --onboot yes --device eth0 --mtu=1500 --bootproto dhcp --hostname test3.example.net
```

which is weird because i add `?static=yes` to the ks url. (i think thats the way to do it?)

Comment: What does the actual kickstart look like after the VM installs?  This is saved in /root/ on the newly installed machine.  Does it contain the proper network line?

Comment: It contains the following line:

`network --onboot yes --device eth0 --mtu=1500 --bootproto dhcp --hostname test3.example.net`

which is weird because i add `?static=yes` to the ks url. (i think thats the way to do it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now by changing this line in the default kickstart template from:

```
network --bootproto <%= @static ? "static --ip=#{@host.ip} --netmask=#{@host.subnet.mask} --gateway=#{@host.subnet.gateway} --nameserver=#{[@host.subnet.dns_primary,@host.subnet.dns_secondary].reject{|n| n.blank?}.join(',')}" : 'dhcp' %> --hostname <%= @host %>
```

to:

```
network --bootproto <%= "static --ip=#{@host.ip} --netmask=#{@host.subnet.mask} --gateway=#{@host.subnet.gateway} --nameserver=#{[@host.subnet.dns_primary,@host.subnet.dns_secondary].reject{|n| n.blank?}.join(',')}" %> --hostname <%= @host %>
```

This way i force using a static ip.

However, i still wonder how to pass that variable to kickstart correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PXELinux template and feed static=yes to your kickstart request

For example I added mine like so ...

```
append initrd=<%= @initrd %> ks=<%= foreman_url('provision')%>&static=yes ksdevice=bootif network kssendmac
```

I associated this with the particular hostgroup that I wanted to have provisioned with static addresses

Answer (score -3):

go to Infrastructure -> subnets --> click on default --> change "boot mode" to static